# Understanding Jekyll and the gh-pages branch when using GitHub Pages

Tags: git, github, jekyll, github-pages

I'm using Jekyll with GitHub Pages (specifically, a project page). I've created 2 branches:

1. `master`
2. `gh-pages`

The [documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/#deploying-jekyll-to-github-pages) explains that the website content is stored in the `gh-pages` branch and that content will be rendered by Jekyll. The output will be available at a URL such as username.github.io/project-name.

If I run `jekyll new mysite` in my local `master` branch, that creates _config.yml, _posts, _sites etc in that branch. At this point if I run `jekyll serve` I can see a basic site at localhost:4000 (which is great).

**My question:**

Considering what I currently have in my `master` branch currently seems to be working, what is the purpose of the `gh-pages` branch? What exactly should be contained in a) `master` branch and b) `gh-pages` branch?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not need the master branch if you want to publish a project website. You will only need gh-pages branch. So, you can delete the master branch after creating the gh-pages branch. Then you upload your website content to gh-pages; doesn't matter if you upload Jekyll folders (so GitHub will build your site) or if you upload your `_site` folder (so GitHub will only display your files as a web server would). That's it.

Comment: Thanks @VirtuaCreative, there seems to be two approaches I could take. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34113444/1709033). I'm wondering what approach people usually take with regards to using Jekyll with GitHub pages?

Comment: you're welcome. I believe you need to understand the locally build of Jekyll. Suppose you want to upload a Jekyll website to a  common Apache web server (not GitHub Pages). You upload the `_site` folder that Jekyll built locally to you. Now, when using GitHub as your host, you can do either, as GitHub builds it automatically for you. About user/organization and project websites in GitHub, the thing is: you can have as many websites as you wish. One for user/organization and multiple for projects. I recommend you to read this [article](http://goo.gl/BUq3ME) for a better overview.

Comment: If you don't have any fancy plugins, the way most of developers do is uploading the Jekyll folder to gh-pages branch and setting GitHub to ignore the local `_site` folder. And if you don't need `master` branch, go on and delete it! And if you don't need more than one website, go for user website, not project. I say that because if you create a project site you will have this domain name: `username.github.io/project`. If a visitor tries `username.github.io` he'll find a 404 error. Hope to have helped!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading [Github pages documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/) :

#### If you want to push your code and have Github generating your site :

You will only need to version your code and NOT the generated pages. So, only one branch is needed.

1. For a user/organisation Github page
   (`github.com/username/username.github.io`), you publish your code in
   `master`.
2. For a project page (`github.com/username/projectRepository`), you publish your code in `gh-pages`. Here you don't need a `master` branch.

#### If you need to **generate your site locally** and only send the generated pages on Github :

You will need to version both your code and you generated pages. So, two branches will be needed.

3. `User/organisation` repository : base code goes in `code` (or
   whatever you name it) branch, and generated pages goes in `master`.
4. `Project` repository : base code goes in `master` (or whatever you
   name it) branch, and generated pages goes in `gh-pages`.

Comment: Can I ask why 2 branches are needed locally (your last bullet point), yet only `gh-pages` is needed on the server (your step 2)?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Which approach is recommended with reference to using Jekyll with GitHub Project Pages?

Comment: It depends if you can leave github generate your pages, go 2. If you have to generate locally (eg: because you're using exotic plugins not in use on Github) you go 4.

Comment: Considering Jekyll generates my pages both on the server and locally (I'm not using any exotic plug-ins), would that indicate point 2 is the approach I should take (instead of point 4)?

Comment: Yes. If Github generates you pages, you don't need to version them. So, only a `gh-pages` branch is needed.

Answer (score 0):

#### As described in github gh-pages:

> Roll vanilla, or generate a site for your project to quickly get started.

`gh-pages` are simply a github specific branch which allow you to use it as your web site.

It means that if you have `index.html` in this page you will be able to view it in your browser directly.

you this link format: `username.github.io/project_name`

More info can be found here: https://pages.github.com/

Comment: Thanks. So should the content of `master` and `gh-pages` be exactly the same? Do I even need a `master` branch? The documentation seems to suggest config etc goes into `master` and content only goes into `gh-pages`.

Comment: You can only use `gh-pages` both for content (serving  index.html/ or REAME.md) and for your code.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean?

Comment: you can use the same branch for your code and for your docs, that's the button line.

Comment: Thanks. I did know that it was possible to use both code and content in the same branch, I just wondered if that was the recommended thing to do. If you read the first paragraph [here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/#project-pages) you'll see it mentions web **content** goes in `gh-pages`. It seemingly suggests content only goes into this branch because it says nothing about code.

Comment: If you want you can use master as well, but it can cause you to manage the code in 2 different branches.